# Find the series $\sum A_{k}$ if $A_{k} = |a_{2^{k}N}| + |a_{2^{k}N+1}| + \cdot \cdot \cdot + |a_{2^{k+1}N-1}| $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pattern-recognition

Pick a natural number $N \geq 1$. For $k \geq 0$, where $A_{k}$ is defined as $$A_{k} = \left( |a_{2^{k}N}| + |a_{2^{k}N+1}| \right) + \left( |a_{2^{k}N+2}| + |a_{2^{k}N+3}| \right) + \cdot \cdot \cdot \left( |a_{2^{k+1}N-2}| + |a_{2^{k+1}N-1}| \right)$$

Write $\sum_{k \geq 0} A_{k}$.

I am immensely confused by this. How did $A_{k}$ went from $N+1, N+2, N+3$ to $N-2, N-1$ ? Where is the turning point?

Below is what I have tried.

Judging by the first few terms, the pattern seems to be $$\sum_{k \geq 0} A_{k} = \sum_{k \geq 0} |a_{2^{k}N+k}|$$

However, I don't understand the last two terms, if $k$ is going to $\infty$, how did $A_{k}$ end up as $$|a_{2^{k+1}N-2}| + |a_{2^{k+1}N-1}|$$

And how does this form the series $\sum_{k \geq 0} A_{k}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A_k$ goes from $2^k N,2^k N+1,\cdots,2^{k+1}N-1$,  $2^k N$ in total. Then
$$\sum_{k\geq 0}A_k=\sum_{k\geq N}|a_k|$$.

**Edit.**

Maybe you can try $k=2,N=3$ or some others. Then
$$A_0=|a_3|+|a_4|+|a_5|$$
$$A_1=|a_6|+|a_7|+\cdots+|a_{11}|$$
...

So from the form of $A_0$ and $A_1$, you can find the sum $\sum_{k\geq 0}A_k=\sum_{k\geq 3}|a_k|=\sum_{k\geq N}|a_k|$.

Comment: Can you dive deeper? I am not sure I follow the logic here.

Comment: I still don't understand the last two terms $|a_{2^{k+1}N-2}| + |a_{2^{k+1}N-1}|$

Comment: @SirouEwei If $k=2,N=3$, then index $2^{k+1}N-2=2^3\cdot 3-2=22$.

Comment: Could you elaborate how do the last two terms fit into the pattern of the series? If we just look at first few terms, suppose I substitute $N=3$ for $A_{0}$, then I get $|a_3| + |a_4| + |a_5| + |a_6| + \cdot \cdot \cdot + |a_4| + |a_5|$. Like what's the pattern there? Why did it go from $|a_5| + |a_6| $ to $|a_4| + |a_5|$. Where does it take a turn?

Comment: Also, since we have $\sum_{k \geq N} |a_{k}|$, can we say the series $\sum_{k \geq 1} |a_{k}| = \sum_{k \geq N} |a_{k}| + \sum_{k = 1}^{N} |a_{k}|$ ? @JwJJJJ

Comment: For the question of $|a_3|+|a_4|+|a_5|+|a_6|+\cdots+|a_4|+|a_5|$, the sum must stop at $|a_5|$ so the sum is actually $|a_3|+|a_4|+|a_5|$.

Comment: Why must the sum stop at $|a_5|$ ?

Comment: The last term of this sum is $|a_5|$.